# ORA-00905: missing keyword IN TOAD

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ALTER TABLE TGT_EMP MODIFY COLUMN TOTAL_SALARY DECIMAL[(P[,S])];
```

Im encountering a problem when executing the line of code above in toad. The Problem is showing at decimal(missing keyword). Please help me to get it solved. My motive is to change the data type of column named as total_Salary in Table Named TGT_EMP

Comment: You're supposed to specify precision and scale. E.g. `decimal(12,2)`.

Comment: Please fix your shift key. IT'S APPARENTLY BROKEN AS YOU CAN'T write lower case letters.

Comment: Thou shalt not use upper case for questions in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `column` keyword. It's just

```
ALTER TABLE TGT_EMP MODIFY TOTAL_SALARY DECIMAL(9,3);
```

Also your datatype declaration looks a bit odd. But I'm not sure if that's what you are actually running.